# Change Document Restrictions

Tags: itext

I am using iText to fill out PDF AcroForms. The original form has a Security Method of No Security, but Changing the Document and Document Assembly are Not Allowed. After I fill (and flatten) the document, the resulting PDF still has the same document restrictions as the original form. Is there a way to allow document assembly in the filled in PDF? I have tried to adjust the WriterProperties, using the EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_ASSEMBLY, but that was not succesfull. [image]

Comment: Please be aware that the "Document Restrictions Summary" summarizes restrictions that arise from a number of factors. You might want to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65021738/1729265) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51438136/1729265)...

Comment: In other words, to have document assembly allowed, open the pdf in some other Adobe Acrobat program, not in Adobe Acrobat Reader.

Comment: Thanks @mkl. I am using Adobe Acrobat Pro DC and was still seeing the restrictions. I was able to work around the restrictions by Using the "Save a Copy" option from within Adobe. The copy did not have the same restrictions.

Comment: Then some other of the reasons mentioned in the referenced answers applied. Without the file itself i could only guess.